# Why most compilers can't do modulus calculation combination optimization?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

```
unsigned long f1(unsigned long num) {
    if (num % 5L == 0 && num % 3L == 0) { return 1000; }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long f2(unsigned long num) {
    if (num % 15L == 0) { return 1000; }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler result:

```
f1(unsigned long):
        movabs  rdx, -3689348814741910323
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rcx, rdi
        mul     rdx
        mov     rax, rdx
        and     rdx, -4
        shr     rax, 2
        add     rdx, rax
        mov     rax, rdi
        sub     rcx, rdx
        movabs  rdx, -6148914691236517205
        mul     rdx
        mov     rax, rdx
        and     rdx, -2
        shr     rax
        add     rdx, rax
        sub     rdi, rdx
        or      rdi, rcx
        cmp     rdi, 1
        sbb     rax, rax
        and     eax, 1000
        ret
f2(unsigned long):
        movabs  rax, -1229782938247303441
        imul    rdi, rax
        movabs  rax, 1229782938247303441
        cmp     rax, rdi
        sbb     rax, rax
        not     rax
        and     eax, 1000
        ret
```

tried GCC, msvc, clang, Java C2, C# JIT
I think `num % 5 == 0 && num % 3 == 0` can be optimized into `num % 15 == 0`, but most compilers won't do it.
Is there any situations that will make these compare different or just no one just think about it?

by icebp: godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/z/Po1Tsq)

Comment: Do not post images of code.  Post as text.

Comment: okay, I was posting the image because I want to show the compile result

Comment: You can post a link to godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Po1Tsq

Comment: post the assembly output as code (text, not image) and then as a bonus post a link to godbolt for us to tinker with.

Comment: Looks like fizzbuzz to me :-)

Comment: Maybe it is just a pretty uncommon pattern, so compilers do not recognize it as optimizable.

Comment: If we change the divisors to `4L` and `8L`, then [GCC combines the tests](https://godbolt.org/z/qrjzE1). This proves there is no semantic barrier to making the optimization—there is no issue of sequencing or observable or undefined behavior. Therefore, the reason is, as Eugene Sh. suggested, likely just that the pattern is uncommon and so desire to add it to compilers as not arisen.

Comment: but `num % 8L` includes `num % 4L`?

Comment: @Cyl18: But `num % 4L == 0` does not include `num % 8L == 0`. So, with 4 on the left, if there were some reason evaluation of the right operand had to be contingent on the left operand, the compiler could not combine them; it would have to do the 4 test before the 8 test. Since it combines them, this demonstrates the evaluation of the right operand is not contingent.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sorry, rereading my comment, it looked rude, which wasn't my goal. The point is, we have questions everyday asking why compilers don't perform an optimization, and the answer is almost always that they don't because nobody has implemented it. If people care about this optimization and cannot implement it themselves, they can file a bug/enhancement report. If they really want it, they can pay someone to implement it.

Comment: Aside: Cyl18,  `L` not needed with theses constants.  A `u` suffix would be a nice touch, but even that is not truly needed here either, but might quiet some pedantic warnings about mixed sign-ness.

Answer (score 0):

This is surely not a comprehensive answer, but keep in mind that boolean operators in C use [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means that for `if (A && B)`, if `A` is false then `B` is never evaluated because the whole condition can never be true. Similarly for `if (A || B)`, if `A` is true then `B` is never evaluated because the whole condition can never be false.

In your specific case, this means that if `num % 5 == 0` is false, then it never has to evaluate `num % 3 == 0` because the whole condition can never be true.

Comment: if I change && to &, godbolt shows the same compile result: https://godbolt.org/z/chss5n

Comment: This is not a reason at all. The so-called short circuit rule is not a barrier to optimization in this case, as the code has the same semantics regardless of whether the right operand is evaluated and discarded or never evaluated.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah I wasn't sure if this was relevant. But I thought it would be worth pointing out. Maybe it would have been better as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that yet.

Comment: It would be a reason in case `% 3` and `% 5` were less expensive than `% 15`. But looks like they are not